# Making Ads in Android

Tags: android

I want to make a free app but generate revenue in some way, so I figured I would put ads in my app. Does anyone have any recommendations on the best/easiest way to do so? Thanks

Comment: First choose an [advertising service](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6262918/741249), then follow it's instructions on how to set it up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

admob is the most popular solution for advertisement ini android: http://www.admob.com/

Comment: Is there any fee to use them?

Comment: Recent messages in AdMob discussion group are quite discouraging. It would be nice to have some more alternatives for this.

Comment: See some more answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2471417/embedding-ads-on-android-app

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed MobFox (http://www.ProjectJourneyman.com/android-ad-revenue-mobfox) as well as Admob vs. MobClix (http://www.ProjectJourneyman.com/android-ad-revenue-mobclix-admob).  I currently use all three to maximize my revenue.  Admob is more of a fallback, though.

Once you get more established you can tweak things to improve your revenue, but my first recommendation is to add another ad company to your arsenal besides Admob.

Answer (score 0):

I've also tried Leadbolt as they have a version for apps (leadboltapps.com). They do banners but also other adtypes - notifications, interstitials which deliver revenue results (eCPMs) that are much better that admod. I got an eCPM of $2.83 in US but I've heard of people that got consistent $6 eCPMs and even higher. They have a SDK plus html methods for integration which means you can get started very easily. You can sign up on their website and get started very quickly.